# Can a wizard ever gain more at-will spells?

Tags: dnd-4e

Can a wizard, through levels, races, paragon paths, epic destinies, or feats, ever gain more at-will spells?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! If you have any questions, please check out our [FAQ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) and when you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you tell us why you need more at-wills, we can tell you how to achive the same goal easier. Getting more at-will is usually not a great investment.

Answer (score 2):

## Be a Human

That'll get you a third power from the choices you had at level 1. There's no other way that I know of to "purchase" more abilities from *that* list.

But don't stop there. You can always...

## Poach from other classes

Check out the Half-Elf Polymath paragon path.

> Broad Dilettante (16th level): Choose a 1st-level at-will attack power from any class that is different from yours. You gain that power

Or take a Multiclass feat like Binding Initiate.

> Benefit: You gain training in one skill from the binder warlock’s class skills list. You also gain proficiency with rods and wands.
>       Choose a binder pact boon. You gain the at-will attack power and the utility power it grants at 1st level as encounter powers.

---

There are plenty of ways to get other at-will powers. Some feats/paragon paths/epic destinies/items just straight up grant you at-will powers, though they aren't always attack powers if that's what you're looking for.  Creating and maintaining a comprehensive list of those would be next to impossible. You're better off looking for something specific you want your character to do rather than just amassing as many at-wills as possible.

Comment: If there is something specific you want to be able to do at-will, please update your question to reflect that and I'll edit to be more specific.

Comment: The Half Elf's Dilettante class feature + Versatile Master feat at paragon also allows this. There's also a way to gain Magic Missile for free via the Blackstaff Aprentice Theme.